# The query including the joining of three table is not working?

Tags: mysql

In the given code I am not able to join tbl_schedule with the other two table time(A),time(B):

```
$query="SELECT A.train_no AS AA, A.station_id AS AB, A.arrival AS AC, A.dept AS AD, B.station_id AS AE, B.arrival AS AF, B.dept AS AG FROM TIME AS A,TIME AS B,tbl_schedule WHERE A.train_no = B.train_no
AND A.station_id ='$f' AND B.station_id ='$t' AND sc_tr_num=A.train_no";
$rs=mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['AA']."</td> <td>".$stname1."</td> <td>" .$row['AC'] ."</td>
        <td>".$row['AD'] . "</td><td>".$stname2. "</td><td>".$row['AF'] . "</td><td>" .$row['AG']. "
        </td><td>".$row['sc_mon']."</td><td>".$row['sc_tue']."</td><td>".$row['sc_wed']."</td>
        <td>".$row['sc_thu']."</td><td>".$row['sc_fri']."</td><td>".$row['sc_sat']."</td>
        <td>".$row['sc_sun']."</td></tr>"."<a href='Reservation.php'>Click Me</a><tr><td>";
}
```

Comment: can you clean up your code, a little bit?

Comment: Are you saying that it works fine until you add tbl_schedule to it? That seems hard to believe. Moreover, how do you know since you aren't actually grabbing any data from the tbl_schedule table?

Comment: yup.. it is working until i include tbl_schedule.. don't bother about $stname1,$stname2.. the values retrieving from tbl_schedule is $row['sc_mon']."</td><td>".$row['sc_tue']."</td><td>".$row['sc_wed']."</td>
        <td>".$row['sc_thu']."</td><td>".$row['sc_fri']."</td><td>".$row['sc_sat']."</td>
        <td>".$row['sc_sun']

Comment: I do not understand why there is 2 aliases on the same table (TIME) but if you want a query to join over the 3 tables you have to link them...

In you query there is a link between TIME(A) and TIME(B) but no one with tbl_schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining table can be done the following way (to be adapted to your needs)

Table A

```
+------+------
| idA  | valueA...
```

Table B

```
+------+------
| idB  | fkA (idA)...
```

Table C

```
+------+------
| idC  | fkC (idB)...
```

If you want to query over these 3 tables your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT A.valueA, B.valueB, C.valueC FROM A, B, C WHERE A.idA = B.fkA AND B.idB = C.fkC
```